# Magento 2 : Import product with custom csv

Tags: magento2, product, import, custom, csv

I have a custom product csv file https://drive.google.com/file/d/1f9t4REhn8-Ant58zRB6S0yRx1Rh1PctX/view?usp=sharing
how can I import it in Magento 2. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You should [read the doc](https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/system/data-import.html) about import process.

This link can be usefull too to know wich fields must be set for your usecase : https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/system/data-attributes-product.html

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I know how to import, My problem is the csv file quite complex and different structure by default Magento. and I need to know how to solve it.

Comment: You must rename your csv columns and apply data transformations in order to import it into Magento.
If you don't want to do it manually, or if there is too many rows, you can do it programmaticaly by  reading your file, parsing/sanitizing data and print in a new well formated. 

I recently built a cli tool in php for this purpose, since a client needed to include thousands of products from different csv files, but you'd better to know php if you want to use it. You can find it on my github : https://github.com/AriartWt/csvCompiler

Comment: Thank you, you said exactly what I need, I will try your way.
Can you show me how to use your tool?

Comment: I wrote a detailed documentation that can be found on the repo ( https://github.com/AriartWt/csvCompiler#presentation ). If you encounter a bug, or have some trouble with it, you can post an issue and i will try my best to help you.

Comment: I have a question in my csv file there are many fields that don't exist in Magento, can your tool automatically generate it?

Comment: The csvCompiler will only use the columns that you define in the configuration file at index `$config["output"]["columns_map"]`. IF you wan't to skip some columns, just don't sepecify it in the columns map.